# Monospace 10px in ubuntu 16.10 has invalid size

Tags: ubuntu, freetype, monospace, fontconfig

[Problem in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUWRs.png)

Why? How fix it?
10px in 16.10 too small ("p" - 10px), but 11px is too big ("p" - 12px)
In 14.04 normal font size ("p" - 11px)

```
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm... i found this path in ubuntu freetype 2.5.2 and bug fixed!

Sample: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=129090

```
# Description: revert commit which creates regressions in gtk
# Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/freetype/+bug/972223
# Debian: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=636776
--- a/src/truetype/ttdriver.c
+++ b/src/truetype/ttdriver.c
@@ -246,10 +246,7 @@
     FT_Request_Metrics( size->face, req );

     if ( FT_IS_SCALABLE( size->face ) )
-    {
       error = tt_size_reset( ttsize );
-      ttsize->root.metrics = ttsize->metrics;
-    }

     return error;
   }
```